# Message queue: request-response architecture

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I am just learning MQs so in this question I need help with understanding how conversation between two servers is happening. I have following architecture:

[image]

*Interaction example:*

1. I am sending `'{"operation": "get", "key": key}'` to `Request
   chanell` or `'{"operation": "set", "key": key, "value": value}'`
   form **Gateway Server**https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCAUr.png
2. Expecting **Cache Server** answering with `value` and `success flag`

*Questions:*

- Is it Robust architecture?
- Do I use MQ correctly?
- Should I add `req_id:` parameter to message body in order to find response?
- What about performance?